# pcregrep: how to match only the first occurence?

Tags: regex, pcregrep

I have a lot of files in the following format:

```
SIMPLE
{
    residualControl
    {
        p               1e-4;
        U               1e-4;
        "(k|omega|epsilon)" 1e-4;
    }
    nNonOrthogonalCorrectors 0;
    pRefCell        0;
    pRefValue       0;

}

potentialFlow
{
    nNonOrthogonalCorrectors 10;
}

relaxationFactors
{
    fields
    {
        p               0.3;
    }
    equations
    {
        U               0.7;
        "(k|omega|epsilon).*" 0.7;
    }
}
```

I want to match the following block of text in all files located in the folder `$FOAM_TUTORIALS/incompressible`:

```
    residualControl
    {
       // line 1
       // line 2
       // ...etc
    }
```

When I use `pcregrep` as follow:

```
    pcregrep --color -r -M "residualControl.*\n.*\{(.*\n)*" $FOAM_TUTORIALS/incompressible/
```

it matches the other lines too (see the comment below):

```
SIMPLE
{
    residualControl
    {
        p               1e-4;
        U               1e-4;
        "(k|omega|epsilon)" 1e-4;
    } // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< I want it to stop match here. But it matches also the lines below
    nNonOrthogonalCorrectors 0;
    pRefCell        0;
    pRefValue       0;

}

potentialFlow
{
    nNonOrthogonalCorrectors 10;
}

relaxationFactors
{
    fields
    {
        p               0.3;
    }
    equations
    {
        U               0.7;
        "(k|omega|epsilon).*" 0.7;
    }
}
```

Could you please tell me how to modify the regex to match only the first block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex for search:

```
pcregrep --color -r -M '^\h*residualControl\s*{[^}]*}' $FOAM_TUTORIALS/incompressible/
```

```
residualControl
{
    p               1e-4;
    U               1e-4;
    "(k|omega|epsilon)" 1e-4;
}
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `^\h*`: Match 0 or more horizontal whitespaces at a line start
- `residualControl\s*`: Match string `residualControl` followed by 0 or more whitespaces (including newlines)
- `{`: Match opening `{`
- `[^}]*`: Match 0 or more characters (including newlines) that are not `}`
- `}`: Match closing `}`

Comment: PCRE also doesn't require `{` to be escaped but escaping won't harm here so `'^\h*residualControl\s*\{[^}]*\}'` will also produce same results.